# CSS - Why am I not able to set height and width of <a href> elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create css buttons by using the following html markup:

```
<a href="access.php" class="css_button_red">Forgot password</a>
```

But it ends up being not bigger than the text in the middle. Even though I've set the class's height and width.

You can preview the problem here btw, www.matkalenderen.no
Notice the first button, that's a form button and it's using it's own class. At first I tried to use the same class on the css button as well and the same problem appeared, so I tried to separate them into their own classes. In case there was some kind of crash. But it didn't matter anyway.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As the others have said, by default `<a>` is an inline element, and inline elements can't specify a width or height. You can change it to be a block element like this:

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

Though it will then display (unsurprisingly) as a block, sitting on its own, outside the flow of the surrounding text. A better solution is to use `display: inline-block` which might be a best-of-both-worlds solution depending on your situation.

See [PPK's writeup](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock) about it.

> The real use of this value is when you want to give an inline element a width. In some circumstances some browsers don't allow a width on a real inline element, but if you switch to display: inline-block you are allowed to set a width.

Comment: Haha! Inline-block fixed alot of things for me! When using just display:block, the whole button was misaligned. But now, it follows the same flow as the form button :) Thanx!

Comment: Be careful with inline-block.  It is not uniformly supported by browsers.  Know your analytics and make sure it displays well in all statistically significant browsers for your site.  Notibly, IE 6 and 7 both lack solid inline-block support. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03

Comment: @kingjeffrey Quirksmode states that IE6&7 only have issues with inline-block when it is applied to elements which are not natively inline. Hence, it won't be a problem when applied to an `<a>`.

Comment: Ok, seems to work fine :) Although I'm having some trouble with an invisible margin being applied to the <a> element. But that's probably a different question :)

Answer (score 9):

Because <a>'s are inline elements by default. In CSS define `a { display:block; }` and height and width settings will be applied.

Of course, you may not want to declare all anchor tags as block level elements, so filter by class or id as needed.

Comment: Thanx, I thought I'd already tried that. Now all of a sudden it worked. Man, just shows how important it is to have a structured mind when it comes to coding css!

Answer (score 5):

I think the most proper solution is `display: inline-block;` which will allow you to set `height` for the element that still will be treated as `inline` element.