# I can't figure out how to control the CSS height of an ahref

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I have an HTML page with embedded CSS styling.  It has a form with an input button that says "Submit Payment" using #fjButton and height of 54, which gets obeyed. I also have an  that has an id #fjButton2 with a height of 14... both set to !important.  The #fjButton2 doesn't get obeyed.  Im's sure it's some stupid thing, but i just can't figure it out... the  stays at 32px no matter what i do.  See it at:
https://codepen.io/johnstonf/full/YzwGqNO

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test-Store</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Inter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Landing page styling -->
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: #f2f4f9;
        }

        h3, h5{
            font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 100;
        }

        h3{
            font-size: 36px;
        }

        h5{
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        p, label{
            font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
        }

        hr{
            color:#fff;
            background-color: #fff;
            border-top:1px solid #fff;
            margin-top:10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #container{
            width:1200px;
            margin:0 auto;
            padding-top: 3%;
        }

        .column-6{
            text-align: center;
            width: 50%;
            float:left;
        }

        #left-wrapper{
            background-color: #72cca7;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #dce0e6;
            border-radius: 14px;
            border: 3px solid black;
            margin-right: 14px;
            margin-top: 14px;
            padding: 13px;  
        }

        #right-wrapper{
            padding-top: 13px;
            margin-top: 13px;
            border-radius: 14px;
            border: 3px solid black;
            margin-right: 14px;

            background-color: #72cca7;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #dce0e6;
            border-radius: 14px;
            border: 3px solid black;
            margin-right: 14px;
            margin-top: 14px;
            padding: 13px;  
        }

        #profile-pic{
            width:200px;
            display:block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-radius: 50%;
            float:left;

        }

        #left-wrapper-header{
            min-width:50%;
            float:left;
            padding-left:20px;

        }

        #left-wrapper-header h3{
            color:#fff;

        }

        #right-wrapper h3{
            color: #10a195;
        }

        .Z9999{
            margin-left: 1px;
            width: 99%;
        }

        /* ------------------------ FORM FIELDS ------------------------ */

        .form-field-12{
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 6px;
            padding-top: 3px;
        }

        .form-field-6{
            width: 50%;
            float:left;
            margin-bottom: 1px;
        }


        select{
            width: 100%;
            height: 25px!important;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #dce0e6;
            padding: 1px 2px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            font-size: 20px;
            color:  #44464a;
        }

        input{
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #dce0e6;
            height:40px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            color:  #44464a;
            width: 95%;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }



        input::placeholder {
          color: #9fa1a6;
        }

        /* ------------------------ BUTTON STYLING ------------------------ */


        #fjButton {
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #dce0e6;
            font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif;;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            color:  #44464a;
            height: 54px !important;
            width: 30%;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-decoration:none;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #fjButton2 {
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #dce0e6;
            font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif;;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            color:  #44464a;
            height: 14px !important;
            width: 30%;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-decoration:none;
            margin: 0px;
        }



        .myButton:hover {
            opacity: .6;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width:1200px){
            #container{
                width:80%;
            }

            .column-6{
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width:800px){
            #container{
                width:100%;
            }

            .Z9999{
                margin-left: 20px;
                width: 100px;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Success page styling -->
    <style type="text/css">
        h4{
            font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        #box{
            max-width: 500px;
            margin:0 auto;
            margin-top: 100px;
            padding:30px;
            background-color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #dce0e6;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
        }

        .myButton {
            background-color:#72cca7;
            background-color:#26367e;
            display:inline-block;
            cursor:pointer;
            color:#ffffff;
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:17px;
            padding:10px;
            width:30%;
            border-radius: 0;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-align: center;
            transition: .3s;
        }
        .myButton:hover {
            opacity: .6;
        }

        #succes-icon{
            width: 100px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .StripeElement {
          box-sizing: border-box;

          height: 40px;

          padding: 10px 12px;

          border: 1px solid transparent;
          border-radius: 4px;
          background-color: white;

          box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1;
          -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
          transition: box-shadow 150ms ease;
        }

        .StripeElement--focus {
          box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df;
        }

        .StripeElement--invalid {
          border-color: #fa755a;
        }

        .StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
          background-color: #fefde5 !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="column-6">
            <div id="left-wrapper">
                <img id="profile-pic" src="{% static 'images/logo-20may29.png' %}">
                <div id="left-wrapper-header">
                    <h3>Item Purchase</h3>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:left"></div>
                <hr>
                <!-- Add form here -->
                <form action="{% url 'charge' %}" method="post" id="payment-form">
                    <div class="form-field-12">
                        <label for="amount"><b>Pick a product from this dropdown:</b></label>
                        <select required name="amount" id="amount">
                          <option selected value="1">$1 CAD ------> TEST</option>
                          <option value="1">$1 CAD -----> 1 item</option>
                          <option value="2">$2 CAD -----> 2 items</option>
                          <option value="3">$3 CAD ----> 3 items</option>
                          <option value="4">$4 CAD ----> 4 items</option>
                          <option value="5">$5 CAD ---> 5 items</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-field-6">
                        <label for="email"><strong>* Enter your email address:</strong></label>
                        <input required type="email" name="email" placeholder="* email...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-field-6">
                        <label for="username"><strong>* Desired username / login name:</strong></label>
                        <input required type="text" name="username" placeholder="* username...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-field-6">
                        <label for="email"><strong>Enter your Dogs name:</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" name="dog" placeholder="Dogs name...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field-6">
                        <label for="email"><strong>Enter your Favorite beer:</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" name="beer" placeholder="Favorite beer...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-field-6">
                        <label for="country"><strong>* Enter your Country:</strong></label>
                        <input required type="text" name="country" placeholder="* Country...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-field-6">
                        <label for="phone"><strong>* Enter your phone number:</strong></label>
                        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="* Phone..."
                               pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
                               required>
                        <small>Format: 123-456-7890</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row">
                      <label for="card-element">
                        <strong>Credit or debit card</strong>
                      </label>
                      <div id="card-element">
                        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                  </div>

                    <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div style="clear:left">
                  </div>
                  <hr>

                    <input  id="fjButton" style="background-color:#10a195;height:12px" type="submit" value="Submit Payment" name="">
                     <hr>

                     <a href="https://opp.ca" target="_blank" id="fjButton2" style="background-color:#10a195; height:77px"   >OPP Homepage</a>
                     <br><br><br><br>

                </form>         
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column-6">
            <div id="right-wrapper">
                <img class="form-field-12" src="{% static 'images/Z9999.png' %}">
                <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;We appreciate you!</h3>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Create a Stripe client.
        var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_blahblah');

        // Create an instance of Elements.
        var elements = stripe.elements();

        // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
        // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
        var style = {
          base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
              color: '#aab7c4'
            }
          },
          invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
          }
        };

        // Create an instance of the card Element.
        var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

        // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
        card.mount('#card-element');

        // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
        card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
          var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
          if (event.error) {
            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
          } else {
            displayError.textContent = '';
          }
        });

        // Handle form submission.
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
              // Inform the user if there was an error.
              var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
              errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
              // Send the token to your server.
              stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            }
          });
        });

        // Submit the form with the token ID.
        function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
          // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
          var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
          var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
          hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
          form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

          // Submit the form
          form.submit();
        }
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there should'nt be a space inbetween px and !important, its like this: `height: 20px!important`

Answer (score 1):

I found this finally... [CSS - Why am I not able to set height and width of <a href> elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635244/css-why-am-i-not-able-to-set-height-and-width-of-a-href-elements) and as it states... 
"As the others have said, by default  is an inline element, and inline elements can't specify a width or height. You can change it to be a block element like this":

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

Though it will then display (unsurprisingly) as a block, sitting on its own, outside the flow of the surrounding text. A better solution is to use display: inline-block which might be a best-of-both-worlds solution depending on your situation.

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Height won't have any effect on that `<a>` tag as it has a `display` of `inline`, so you simply need to change its display to something like `inline-block` to make it obey the set height, like

```
     #fjButton2 {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #dce0e6;
        font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif;;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        color:  #44464a;
        height: 14px !important;
        width: 30%;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-decoration:none;
        margin: 0px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

Hope it helps.